# Google chrome passing value of fields in a form

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
      <form name="orderform">
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br />
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" />
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button1" Value="Read" onClick="readText(this.form)">

</form> 
<!-- JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files for security. -->
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
console.log("In");
function readText (form) 
{
    TestVar =form.firstname.value;
    console.log(TestVar);
    chrome.tabs.create({"url":"http://www.google.co.in","selected":true}, function(tab){
       });
}
```

Unfortunately the above code does not print the value of a first name. Could someone please tell me what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: For starters you've got a stray quotation mark inside your console call: `console.log(TestVar");`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. When i copied and pasted it i made a mistake. Will edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your form is in the `<head>` section; move it in the body
2. don't use `form.field`, use the DOM `id` property in conjunction with `document.getElementById()`.
3. Use `var` to define local variables; like this:

   ```
   First name: <input type="text" id="firstname" /><!-- note the use of id=... -->
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
       var TestVar = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
   </script>
   ```
4. use `alert()` for strings and numbers

Here's the full code:

**popup.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="orderform">
    First name:
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
    <br />
    Last name:
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />
    <input type="button" name="button1" value="Read" onclick="readText()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
function readText(){
    var TestVar = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    console.log(TestVar); alert(TestVar);
    chrome.tabs.create({"url":"http://www.google.co.in","selected":true}, function(tab){  });
}
```